# How to add special characters in a string in informatica power center

Tags: informatica

Here is my scenario.

My data comes here like this 1134567/9

and ETL should process as 11-3-4567/9

So i should pass a hyphen after first two bytes and then after next third byte another hypen should be passed. Whats the logic should be in expression transformation?

Any thoughts guys?
Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Teja.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SUBSTR(input_data,1,2)||'-'||SUBSTR(input_data,3,1)||'-'||SUBSTR(input_data,4)
```

Comment: Exactly my logic was also same. I was stuck at one place. Do you know how to get the characters from middle to end of the string using substring? I mean data is 12345/6  i need only from 4 to end of the string. Because after adding the hypen at after the third byte we need rest of the data as it is to be passed. How do you know how many characters you have after adding the third hyphen? Substr(input data, 4). How come added 4? Thanks

Comment: The third argument to the SUBSTR function `length` is optional. If you omit it, it will automatically go to the end of the string.

Comment: Oh got you thanks :)  Your responses are always very quick. I appreciate thanks.